# Can /mnt be safely excluded from system backup? What is BootInfo and boot-sav?

Tags: mount, filesystem, backup

I would normally think to exclude `/mnt` from a system backup then simply remake the empty dir on restoring the system, should the need arise, with `mkdir /mnt`.

I'm curious however at the directory structure found inside:

```
ls **
BootInfo:
sdb1  sdb3  sdb4  sdb5

boot-sav:
sdb1  sdb4
```

All these directories (mount points) are empty.

What is their purpose? Do I need to back them up, or can I just re-create them on system restore, or rather will Ubuntu just recreate them for me if I simply recreate `/mnt`? What creates them in the first instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now believe `boot-sav` is something `boot-repair` (for fixing uefi boots of Ubuntu) depends on, so I think these mount points must have been created by `boot-repair` when I ran it, in the course of it probing my partitions. Hence, I think they can safely be deleted, and safely ignored from any backups...

Happy to be corrected by someone who knows more.

Comment: Thanks, was wondering were these directories come from.